# How do you bind asynchronously to a Kendo UI control?

Tags: kendo-ui, async-await

I've got a drop-down selection box that has 2,000 items in it.  I tried to bind it like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect().Name("kendo-dropdown-manager")
                .DataValueField("Value")
                .DataTextField("Text")
                .Placeholder("Select Entity")
                .BindTo(Model.ManagersList)
```

In my Razor Page, I implement the 'Get' asynchronously:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public IndexModel()
    {
        this.ManagersList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }

    public List<SelectListItem> ManagersList { get; private set; }

    public Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        ViewsController viewsController = new ViewsController();
        List<ManagerViewModel> managers = await viewsController.GetManagersAsync();
        this.ManagersList.AddRange(
            from m in managers
            select new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = m.Id.ToString(),
                Text = m.Name
            });
    }
}
```

When the page appears, the drop down is empty.  If I change 'OnGetAsync' to a completely synchronous version, the drop down is populated correctly.  My page has several similar controls and I don't want to load them up synchronously.  What's the proper way to start an operation and have the Kendo controls catch the results when they're returned?